# c++ default constructors created by compiler

Tags: c++

I recently discover this page (https://cppinsights.io/). I try in it some code:

```
class Base {
};

class Derived : public Base {
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  Base& b = d;
}
```

I understand that compilator creates constructor, move constructor, copy constructor and destructor in Base class, and only constructors in Derived class beacause there is no virtual destructor in Base class. But when I add

```
public :
  ~Base(){}
```

and then

```
public :
  virtual ~Base(){}
```

and I saw some differences in constructors. After first addition compilator also generates move assigment operator and destructor in Derrived class, after second addition - virtual destructor, assigment operator and move assigment operator. Why?

Comment: `Base& b = d;` just memorizes an address (as reference), there is no constructor nor destructor involved

Comment: Please be more specific than "I saw some differences" – include them in your question.

Comment: The pointer to the vtable needs to be set, that's probably what you saw.

Comment: *"and only constructors in Derived class beacause there is no virtual destructor"* - Ah, no. The Derived class isn't crippled just because the base has a non-virtual destructor. It still gets one all of its own. But it isn't invocable polymorphically.

Comment: If I well remember C++ member generation, the assignment operator is also generated at the same time than the copy constructor. I speak about the operator=(const&);

Comment: Nothing gets generated that I don't expect: https://godbolt.org/z/sZwivk no move constructor, copy constructor...

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I mean gets generated by compiler, not gets invoked in runtime

Comment: Gcc only generate the destructors. It does that only once base destructor is user-defined because in this case the destructor is not trivial neither for the base nor for the derived.